# Return sums of multiples of nth

Tags: mysql

Now here's a fun MySQL question, I wonder if it's even possible!

Disclaimer: Although it's very similar question that I asked before, it actually is COMPLETELY different. Just saying before anyone says I've asked this before.

**For this example lets say I want `SUMS()` of multiples of 20.**

I want to `SUM()` the row score and return the date.

Lets say I have the following table sorted by `date ASC`:

### Data

```
score |   date
  4     2000-01-01
  2     2000-01-02
  6     2000-01-03
  1     2000-01-04 //Score 4+2+6+1 = 13
  7     2000-01-05 //Score 4+2+6+1+7 = 20 so return this date
  1     2000-01-06
  2     2000-01-07
  1     2000-01-08
  5     2000-01-09
  1     2000-01-10
  9     2000-01-11 //Score = 39 so far.
  7     2000-01-12 //Score = 46 It's not 40 but is the closest number above 40 so return it.
  3     2000-01-13
  4     2000-01-14
  7     2000-01-15 //Score = 60, return this date.
```

### Expected results:

```
score | date
 20     2000-01-05
 40     2000-01-12
 60     2000-01-15
```

And etcetera. Is it possible to do this in MySQL?

Comment: can we use store function? that may produce faster result on large table.

Comment: @Ashim Saha: using SP doesn't mean something automagically would be faster than something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using SQL Variables, you don't have to keep doing recursive aggregations for every subsequent row to tally up to the given entity.  This does each one in sequence with a flag of which one triggers the multiple of 20.  That result is then processed out only where the "ThisOne" flag is set to 1.

```
select 
      M20.*
   from 
      ( select 
              TransDate,
              score,
              if( @runTotal + Score >= 20 * @multCnt, 1, 0 ) as ThisOne,
              @multCnt := @multCnt + if( @runTotal + Score >= 20 * @multCnt, 1, 0 ) as nextSeq,
              @runTotal := @runTotal + Score
           from Mult20s,
                ( select @multCnt := 1,
                         @runTotal := 0 ) sqlvars
           order by transdate ) M20
   where
      M20.ThisOne = 1
```

Comment: +1 This will be more efficient than my solution.  Just need to convert the running totals to multiples of 20 and it's done: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d44cf/13

Comment: Wow, at first glance this looks like its way over my head :) But that's a great learning example, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Sure, anything's possible :)

```
select
    floor(partial / 20) * 20, min(date)
from
    (select
        (select sum(score) from Scores s2
         where s2.date <= s.date) as partial,
        score,
        date
    from
        Scores s) p
where
    floor(partial / 20) > 0
group by
    floor(partial / 20)
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d44cf/3

Comment: Thank you for your contribution :)